# VB.NET Send Tab key to another application window

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sendmessage, postmessage, windows-messages

I want to send "{TAB}" Key to another application **window**(send the key to the window not to textbox).

I tried:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETHOTKEY, VK_TAB, 0)
```

Nothing happened.

my goal is:

send tab key to my application **Or** other application when the application window is **not** in focus.

(**i know that sendkey is not professional in this case there is no choice**(This is the first time that I'm using it).)

I made many attempts and I always returned to the same result:

**Nothing happened.**

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 8):

[SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) requires the application that you are sending the Keys to, to be active.

From above Link:

> Use SendKeys to send keystrokes and keystroke combinations to the active application.

I order to get around this limitation you will have to resort to using the WinApi Functions.

1. [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [pInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html)
2. [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [pInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html)
3. [sendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [pInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)

See this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/9787352e-6320-43a6-8644-83a29fe27e7b) for an example

Here is a modified example from that Posting:

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                     (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
                     (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfterA As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
    Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                     (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
    Const WM_SETTEXT As Integer = &HC

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim destination As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, "Untitled - Notepad")
        Dim destControl As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(destination, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing)
        SendMessage(destControl, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "Hello" & vbTab & "GoodBye" & vbCrLf)

    End Sub

End Class
```

---

Added an Additional Example using `WM_KEYDOWN` I created another small application with the Window Title set to TestForm and overrode the WndProc Method to determine if the application got the TabKey.

**Sending Form**

```
Public Class Form1

    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                 (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                 (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
    Const VK_TAB As Integer = &H9

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim destination As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, "TestForm")
        SendMessage(destination, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0)

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Test Form**

Put a breakpoint on MyBase.WndProc(m) and look at m to see what has been sent.

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you sending to "Edit" class, i want to sendMessage(TAB KEY) to main window of -non- active aapplication. im using WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP and not WM_SETTEXT.

Comment: @Nmmmm What exactly are you trying to accomplish, the example that you show in your question looks like you are trying to create a HotKey, though the documentation states that vk_Tab is invalid for that purpose. The code that I gave you will send text to the edit control that is part of Notepad. I will add another example to show WM_keyDown working.

Answer (score 1):

Having struggled with this type of this a few times before, i would suggest a couple of things to look at.

The 1st is [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) which includes a dll you can reference from vb.net, and is very simple you use, and well documented. I tend to use that whenever i need to control a 3rd party program.

The other is the [ui automation classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx)
See this for an example:

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html

Answer (score 0):

you need make the other window active first. check [Change focus to another window in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088020/change-focus-to-another-window-in-vb-net) . then use send key.

Comment: read what I wrote again. i want to send keys when the window is not in focus.

Comment: I think you can not sendkeys that if it is not in focus. I'm 50% sure of this :) because I tried it some years ago, and could not figure out how to do it except bring the window to focus first. however, I could be totally wrong.