# Run a batch file on a remote desktop from VBA

Tags: excel, remote-desktop, vba

I am new and seeking help.  I manually open a remote desktop to a server and run a batch file I have sitting on that desktop.  I want to do this thru VBA.  I don't want to see the remote desktop and I would like to know when the batch file is finished running.  Here is the code I have found so far.  It brings me to the password screen for the remote desktop and I must take it from there manually.  What do I need to add to the code to get this done.

`TestVar = Shell("C:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe /v:" & "IP Address", 1)`

The path for the batch file on the remote is: "C:\users\path\desktop\batch.bat"

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to manipulate the Windows logon screen through code, there are API functions, but you'd have to hard code the password in your code!

Comment: @Philip, thanks.  I don't mind hard coding pswd

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't worried about the logon screen, and want to execute commandfs remotely, you need to take a look at **Windows PowerShell**

- [MS Technet - PowerShell INVOKE Command to execute a script on one or more remote computers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx)
- [MS Technet - Running Remote Commands with PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx)

I think this **immensely popular** StackOverFlow topic could prove useful too (See the answer with *200 upvotes* by **Jason R. Coombs**

[Stack Overflow: how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: There is ways to work around it though. Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922300/passing-value-to-excel-inputbox-from-vb-net), and/or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147529/vb-net-send-tab-key-to-another-application-window)

Comment: @mehow yes I have, you will find my comments and upvotes on Sids work

Comment: @mehow, I don't have the pswd issue anymore.  I can get to the remote desktop.  I just need to know how to execute the .bat file that's there.  I am working with VBA.  Thanks

Comment: @mehow Thanks.  I tried it and it just flashes.  Not sure what it is doing.  By reading the lne of code, I dont see how it gets me to the remote computer to run the batch file on the remote computer, not the local computer.  All the examples I have found seem to run the batch on the local computer.  I need remote.

Comment: it's running it on the calling workstation, you needd to run it as a remote process on the target workstation

Comment: @philip, this opens a DOS window, but runs .bat from local machine - strPath = "\\ComputerName\c$\users\Path\Path\file.bat"
Shell strPath.  This opens the remote desktop, but I need addtl code to run the batch:  testvar = Shell("C:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe /v:" & "ComputerName", 1)